# strsplit from a using a space instead of a period

Tags: r, split

I'm new to R, and I'm playing with `strsplit` within a data frame. My data frame uses the following:

```
Student <- c("John Davis","Angela Williams","Bullwinkle Moose","David   Jones",
"Janice Markhammer","Cheryl Cushing","Reuven Ytzrhak","Greg Knox","Joel England",
"Mary Rayburn")
Math <- c(502,600,412,358,495,512,410,625,573,522)
Science <- c(95,99,80,82,75,85,80,95,89,86)
English <- c(25,22,18,15,20,28,15,30,27,18)
student.exam.data <- data.frame(Student,Math,Science,English)
```

I then attempt to use the following to split the `Student` using the following:

`student.exam.data$Student <- strsplit(student.exam.data$Student, " ", fixed = TRUE)`

which produces the following error:

`Error in strsplit(student.exam.data$Student, " ", fixed = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument`

The only way I've found to split my `Student` column is to first substitute the space with a period, using `student.exam.data <- sub("\\s", ".", student.exam.data$Student)` followed by `student.exam.data$Student <- strsplit(student.exam.data$Student, ".", fixed = TRUE)`

Why does  this work this way, and how can I use `strsplit` on whitespace?

Comment: You have a factor, and you need to pass a character to `strsplit`.  Wrap the `x` argument in `as.character`

Comment: (or set `stringsAsFactors = F` when you create the `data.frame`)

Comment: Is there any way to split this outside of the `strsplit` function? I used the `as.character(student.exam.data$Student)`, but `str(student.exam.data$Student)` returns `Factor w/ 10 levels "Angela Wililams",..: 8 1 2 4 6 3 10 5 7 9`, and `strsplit(student.exam.data$Student, " ", fixed = TRUE)` then returns the `Error in strsplit(student.exam.data$Student, " ", fixed = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument` error. It only seems to work as `strsplit(as.character(student.exam.data$Student), " ", fixed = TRUE)`. Do you know why this would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error comes from the fact that data.frame coerces your character vector into a factor, which throws an error with `strsplit`, as said in the documentation.
Either you can do

```
student.exam.data$Student <-  strsplit(as.character(student.exam.data$Student), " ", fixed = TRUE)
```

Or

```
student.exam.data <- data.frame(Student,Math,Science,English, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
student.exam.data$Student <- strsplit(student.exam.data$Student, " ", fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about that coercion and the `stringsAsFactors` argument. Thanks--that'd be the more elegant solution.